# Numpy Array Replace Largest and Smallest Values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Given the following array (in reality, I will use a much larger one):

```
ar = np.random.randn(2,10)
ar.sort()
array([[-2.08265194, -1.54667461, -0.42901332,  0.00365949,  0.60151581,
         0.69619798,  0.69741627,  0.97086132,  1.79259285,  3.2797454 ],
       [-2.06961226, -1.25542722, -0.44750088, -0.27424209, -0.22824756,
         0.4234969 ,  0.61014409,  0.93816367,  1.11788673,  1.74181219]])
```

For each element, I would like to:

1. replace the smallest value with the next absolute value minus itself times 10.
2. replace the largest value with the next absolute value  plus itself times 10.

Example (smallest value, first element): Replace -2.08265194 with -1.54667461 - (1.54667461 * 10) = -17.01342072

Desired result:

```
array([[-17.01342072, -1.54667461, -0.42901332,  0.00365949,  0.60151581,
         0.69619798,  0.69741627,  0.97086132,  1.79259285,  19.718521349999996 ],
       [-13.80969942, -1.25542722, -0.44750088, -0.27424209, -0.22824756,
         0.4234969 ,  0.61014409,  0.93816367,  1.11788673,  12.29675403]])
```

Comment: What is your problem? Since you used `sort` the smallest element is the first one and the largest is the last one. Just replace them via `ar[0]` and `ar[-1]` respectively.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a narrow problem which the OP seems to have solved, but which is unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

These seem to *actually* work. I'll use them unless there is a faster way to do this (I'm setting up a simultation with 1 million iterations, so speed is key).

```
outliers = 1
ar[:,0:outliers] = ar[:,outliers:outliers+1] - np.abs(ar[:,outliers:outliers+1])*10
ar[:,-outliers:] = ar[:,-outliers - 1:-outliers] + np.abs(ar[:,-outliers - 1:-outliers])*10
```